# Azure Logic apps and OCR when 100 blobs uploaded failing

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, ocr, azure-logic-apps, azure-ai

I am doing an Azure logic App that aims to do OCR on an uploaded picture then create the JSON output in another blob using the below sequence, but nothing happens :

[image]

here is detailed configuration per step :

1 - [image]

2 - [image]

3 - [image]

4 - [image]

Comment: At which action is the workflow failing?

Comment: @RithwikBojja ; The logs says it ran successfully, but trigger skipped , but does not say it fails.

Comment: Try to follow my steps to get output as I have got

Answer (score 0):

Below is my **`design`**  which is working as expected:

**conatiner name following foldernames should be given with "/" slash infront of it.**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Example Source URL:`**

`https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename`

**`Output:`**

When a blob added or modified it got triggered like below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But the above script logic is based on a single object no ? and you specify the test.jpg, What would it be for all images in the container ?

Comment: https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/<filename>, storage account name is same for all sources, and container too, 
 and only change is inplace of test.jpg you have use the file name from dynamic content part. You can take this (https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/) part from a compose action and the the filename from trigger output and then combine them in the action or like this https://i.imgur.com/ELQ29Wg.png